# Delete all links and apped a text based on the ID of the clicked link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onclick

i need some help with a javascript code. I have three links, each one have an diferent ID, what i want to do is, when i click in one of those links, the script gets the id, and then delete all the three link and put a text in the place, for example:

```
<div id="main">     
    <div>
    <div id="links">
         <a id="choice1" href="#footer" onclick="createDiv();removeLink();">choice1</a>
         <a id="choice2" href="#footer" onclick="">choice2</a>
         <a id="choice3" href="#footer" onclick="">choice3</a>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I click choice1, all links have to be deleted and create a text "you clicked in choice1", if I click in choice2 the same happens, but this time shows "you clicked in choice2".

I have this javascript, with function to create a div with the text and a function to remove the links. But I don't know how to do to pick the IDs and place the correspondent text.

```
function createDiv()
{
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    main.appendChild(element);
    var text = document.createTextNode("This is the new text");
    element.appendChild(text);  
}
function removeLink()
{
var link = document.getElementById("links");    
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
}
```

I've searched a lot in the internet but I didn't find an effective way to do it. If someone can give a tip how to do that, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: I want to second what Yasin and litelite mention in their answers — use your javascript to attach an event listener. Inline `onclick="..."` handlers should have gone away the moment addEventListener (and attachEvent) were available. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a click listener on the parent container, which is #links and check to see if you click on one of it's link and if you did, get the InnerHTML and replace the innerHTML of your #links div.

```js
document.getElementById('links').addEventListener('click',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
 var target = event.target; 
  if (target.nodeName === 'A'){
      this.innerHTML = 'You clicked on ' + target.innerHTML; 
 }

});
```

```html
<div id="links">
<a id="id-1" href="google.com">Option 1</a>
<a id="id-2" href="google.com">Option 2</a>
<a id="id-3" href="google.com">Option 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Currently all the links say _option 1_ and all your id's are the same

Comment: @litelie just change the text in the id in the a tags. I just copied and pasted it and forgot to change the vals.

Comment: Yes, i realized that. but you should edit your answer so it is correct.

Comment: It works fine, but what i wanted was, when i click on the link, delete the link, create and put a diferent text in the place, not the same text inside the link. But that will be enough. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @ELS no problem. If you want the text to be different than the content of the links just change this.innerHTML to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use event listenners like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38444209/3072566) because they are a better practice in general. But, if you still want/need to use `onclick`, then you can use `this` and pass it to `createDiv`. so your code will look like this :

```js
function createDiv(e)
{
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    var main = document.getElementById("main");
    main.appendChild(element);
    var text = document.createTextNode("you clicked on " + e.innerText);
    element.appendChild(text);  
}
function removeLink()
{
var link = document.getElementById("links");    
    link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">     
    <div>
    <div id="links">
         <a id="choice1" href="#footer" onclick="createDiv(this);removeLink();">choice1</a>
         <a id="choice2" href="#footer" onclick="createDiv(this);removeLink();">choice2</a>
         <a id="choice3" href="#footer" onclick="createDiv(this);removeLink();">choice3</a>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

All the `on*` events pass as an argument the element to which the event occured.

Comment: Awesome, that works great. It's not exactly what i meant, but, it's more than suficient for what I'm doing, I'm very grateful with your help, Thanks.